# how many of the owners in 2013 asked for groom service?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
First table:

Owner_ID    Owner_Name      
   1           Adam
   2          Alberto
   3          Gaby





Second table:

Puppy_ID   servided_date        type_service
    1               01/25/2012      groom
    2               02/18/2013     shower
    3               05/14/2013      groom



 I have this code:

Select count (owner_ID)
        FROM servided_date p, owner o
        WHERE  p.owner_id , o.owner_id
        AND type_service = 'groom'
        AND year(serviced_date) = 2013;
```

I have this code and I am trying to figure out how many owners from 2013 requested service that said "groom"?

Comment: learn how to ask

Answer (score 1):

Replace ',' with '=' in first condition of where clause

```
Select count (owner_ID)
FROM servided_date p, owner o
WHERE  p.owner_id = o.owner_id
  AND type_service = 'groom'
  AND year(serviced_date) = 2013;
```